# You can't use `\lastbox' in vertical mode

Tags: errors, reledmac

Can anyone help me with this error message:

```
! You can't use `\lastbox' in vertical mode.
\do@lineR ...\global \setbox \one@lineR =\lastbox 
                                                  \@writepageofparR \getline...
```

I think it has something to do with the reledmac-package.

a (not very minimal) example:

```
     \documentclass[10pt,a5paper,twoside]{scrbook}
        \usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

        \usepackage[bmargin=2.25cm]{geometry}

        \usepackage{scrpage2}
        \pagestyle{scrheadings}
        \clearscrheadfoot

        \ihead{\headmark}
        %\automark[chapter]{chapter}
        %\automark*[section]{}

        \ohead{\pagemark}
        \setheadsepline{0.4pt}
        \setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont\normalcolor\small}\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\normalfont}

        %Formatierung der Kopfzeilen:
        \addtokomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont}


        \setkomafont{disposition}{\normalcolor\bfseries} %Schrift in Überschriften, Inhaltsverzeichnis

        \clubpenalty=10000
        \widowpenalty=10000

        \usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
        \usepackage[series={A,B,C}]{reledmac}
        \usepackage{reledpar}


        \setgoalfraction{0.85}


        \lineation{section}
        \linenummargin{left}%%right für Zeilennummern rechts
        %\setRlineflag{}



        \linenumincrement*{5}
        \firstlinenum*{0} %Zahl hochsetzen, um Titelei unnummeriert zu haben

        \maxchunks{10000}

        \usepackage{color}
        \usepackage{multicol,multirow, bigdelim}%%times RAUS


        \usepackage{amsmath}
        \usepackage{fontspec}
        \usepackage{polyglossia, xunicode}
        \usepackage{libertine}
        \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine}

        \setmainlanguage{german}
        \setotherlanguage{hebrew}
        \newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Arial} 

        \usepackage[xindy={language=hebrew,glsnumbers=false},counter=pageline,nosuper,nolong]{glossaries}

        \glsSetCompositor{-}% Use - as separator
        \pretocmd{\gls}{\doedindexlabel}{}{}% Call \doedindexlabel at the begining of \gls

        \makeglossaries



        \newglossarystyle{germanhebrew}
        {% base it on the tree style:
          \setglossarystyle{tree}%
          % switch to german
          \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
            {\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
             \setlength{\parskip}{0pt plus 0.3pt}%
             \begin{german}
            }%
            {\end{german}}%
          \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
            \hangindent0pt\relax
            \parindent0pt\relax
            \glsentryitem{##1}\glstreenamefmt{\glstarget{##1}{%
              \texthebrew{\glossentryname{##1}}}}%
            \ifglshassymbol{##1}{\space(\glossentrysymbol{##1})}{}%
            \glstreepredesc\glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space##2\par
          }%
        }




        \input{glossaries.tex}




        \setmainlanguage{german}
        \setotherlanguage{hebrew}
        %\setotherlanguage{arabic}

        %\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.3]{Scheherazade}
        \newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Ezra SIL}



        \newcommand\einzugjid{\hangindent=5mm\hangafter=1}

        \newcommand\speaker[1]{\noindent{#1} \einzugjid
        }

        \newcommand\einzug{\hangindent=5mm\hangafter=1}

        \newcommand\speakerd[1]{\noindent
        {\textsc{#1}} \einzug
        }

      \usepackage{bidi}\autofootnoterule

        \renewcommand{\thefootnoteA}{\fnsymbol{footnoteA}}


        \begin{document}

        \begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
 \setRTL
 \beginnumbering


\pstart {{\begin{small}|\liningnums{140}|\end{small}}} {\RL{ערקלאֶרונג דער אין דיעזעם ליסטשפיעל פאָרקאָממענדען אַבגעקירצטען וואֶרטער.
{ }}} \pend

 \pstart {\RL{\RL{א\makebox(-1,8.75)[r]{\libertineGlyph{uni02DC}}גר.}
    הייסט       אַנדערער געגענריטטער.}} \pend

\pstart {\RL{א\makebox(-1,8.75)[r]{\libertineGlyph{uni02DC}}ז``
    "   "   אונד זאָ ווייטער.}} \pend
\pstart {\RL{\RL{ב\makebox(-1,8.75)[r]{\libertineGlyph{uni02DC}}ב}
    "   "   בעל. בתים}} \pend
\pstart {\RL{\RL{ב\makebox(-1,8.75)[r]{\libertineGlyph{uni02DC}}וו}
    "   "   בראַנטעוויין.}} \pend
\pstart {\RL{\RL{ב\makebox(-1,8.75)[r]{\libertineGlyph{uni02DC}}ע}.
    "   "   בעל קדושין}} \pend
\pstart {\RL{{ג\makebox(-1,8.75)[r]{\libertineGlyph{uni02DC}}ר}
    "   "   געגענריטטער.}} \pend
\pstart {\RL{{ה\makebox(-1,8.75)[r]{\libertineGlyph{uni02DC}}ג}
    "   "   האכצייטסגאַסט. (גאֶסטע)}} \pend
\pstart {\RL{{ה\makebox(-1,8.75)[r]{\libertineGlyph{uni02DC}}ר}
    "   "   האָר רעכט.}} \pend
\pstart {\RL{{ה\makebox(-1,8.75)[r]{\libertineGlyph{uni02DC}}ש}
    "   "   הערר שאָללעם (שולטהייס)}} \pend
\pstart {\RL{מוזיק. "   "   מוזיקאַנטען.}} \pend
\pstart {\RL{{ע\makebox(-1,8.75)[r]{\libertineGlyph{uni02DC}}גר}
    "   "   ערשטער געגענריטטער.
}} \pend
\pstart {\RL{{ע\makebox(-1,8.75)[r]{\libertineGlyph{uni02DC}}ה}
    "   "    עליו השלום.}} \pend
\pstart {\RL{{ע\makebox(-1,8.75)[r]{\libertineGlyph{uni02DC}}ם}
    "   "   ערשטעס מאֶדכען.}} \pend
\pstart {\RL{{ק\makebox(-1,8.75)[r]{\libertineGlyph{uni02DC}}ר}
    "   "   קרייצע.}} \pend
\pstart {\RL{{ש\makebox(-1,8.75)[r]{\libertineGlyph{uni02DC}}טהס}
  " " שולטהייס}} \pend



\pstart
 {{\begin{small}|\liningnums{142}|\end{small}}}

  \LR{8. September 1822}
 \pend


       \endnumbering
  \end{Leftside}









  \begin{Rightside}

  \beginnumbering

   \pstart \pend
   \pstart \pend

\pstart \pend
 \pstart \pend
   \pstart \pend

\pstart \pend
 \pstart \pend
   \pstart \pend

\pstart \pend
 \pstart \pend
   \pstart \pend

\pstart \pend
 \pstart \pend
   \pstart \pend

\pstart \pend

   \pstart \pend
   \pstart \pend


\endnumbering

\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages


        \end{document}
```

Comment: If you want us to help you, you should really provide a complete [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows how this error message is caused.

Comment: `\lastbox` is a tex primitive that you can not use in outer vertical mode, only in parboxes etc, but hard to guess what you did to get that error if you show no code.

Comment: as far as I see, I don't use \lastbox…

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! Rather than posting huge amounts of code it is better to give a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A MWE should be a minimal amount of code to demonstrate your problem. Please cut your code down to a MWE by  successively deleting lines of code until you identify exactly what is causing the problem. At this point you may well be able to fix the issue yourself, however,if not then some one will almost certainly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a missing sequence for 
`\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
 \setRTL
 \beginnumbering
[…]
  \endnumbering
  \end{Rightside}
  \end{pages}
  \Pages`

so one doublepage was filled with two sides and too full.

it runs now with:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,twoside]{scrbook}
        \usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

        \usepackage[bmargin=2.25cm]{geometry}

        \usepackage{scrpage2}
        \pagestyle{scrheadings}
        \clearscrheadfoot

        \ihead{\headmark}
        %\automark[chapter]{chapter}
        %\automark*[section]{}

        \ohead{\pagemark}
        \setheadsepline{0.4pt}
        \setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont\normalcolor\small}\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\normalfont}

        %Formatierung der Kopfzeilen:
        \addtokomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont}


        \setkomafont{disposition}{\normalcolor\bfseries} %Schrift in Überschriften, Inhaltsverzeichnis

        \clubpenalty=10000
        \widowpenalty=10000

        \usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
        \usepackage[series={A,B,C}]{reledmac}
        \usepackage{reledpar}


        \setgoalfraction{0.85}


        \lineation{section}
        \linenummargin{left}%%right für Zeilennummern rechts
        %\setRlineflag{}



        \linenumincrement*{5}
        \firstlinenum*{0} %Zahl hochsetzen, um Titelei unnummeriert zu haben

        \maxchunks{10000}

        \usepackage{color}
        \usepackage{multicol,multirow, bigdelim}%%times RAUS


        \usepackage{amsmath}
        \usepackage{fontspec}
        \usepackage{polyglossia, xunicode}
        \usepackage{libertine}
        \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine}

        \setmainlanguage{german}
        \setotherlanguage{hebrew}
        \newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Arial} 

        \usepackage[xindy={language=hebrew,glsnumbers=false},counter=pageline,nosuper,nolong]{glossaries}

        \glsSetCompositor{-}% Use - as separator
        \pretocmd{\gls}{\doedindexlabel}{}{}% Call \doedindexlabel at the begining of \gls

        \makeglossaries



        \newglossarystyle{germanhebrew}
        {% base it on the tree style:
          \setglossarystyle{tree}%
          % switch to german
          \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
            {\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
             \setlength{\parskip}{0pt plus 0.3pt}%
             \begin{german}
            }%
            {\end{german}}%
          \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
            \hangindent0pt\relax
            \parindent0pt\relax
            \glsentryitem{##1}\glstreenamefmt{\glstarget{##1}{%
              \texthebrew{\glossentryname{##1}}}}%
            \ifglshassymbol{##1}{\space(\glossentrysymbol{##1})}{}%
            \glstreepredesc\glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space##2\par
          }%
        }




        \input{glossaries.tex}




        \setmainlanguage{german}
        \setotherlanguage{hebrew}
        %\setotherlanguage{arabic}

        %\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.3]{Scheherazade}
        \newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Ezra SIL}



        \newcommand\einzugjid{\hangindent=5mm\hangafter=1}

        \newcommand\speaker[1]{\noindent{#1} \einzugjid
        }

        \newcommand\einzug{\hangindent=5mm\hangafter=1}

        \newcommand\speakerd[1]{\noindent
        {\textsc{#1}} \einzug
        }

      \usepackage{bidi}\autofootnoterule

        \renewcommand{\thefootnoteA}{\fnsymbol{footnoteA}}


\begin{document}



\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
 \setRTL
 \beginnumbering


\pstart {{\begin{small}|\liningnums{140}|\end{small}}} {\RL{ערקלאֶרונג דער אין דיעזעם לוסטשפיעל פאָרקאָממענדען אַבגעקירצטען וואֶרטער.
{ }}} \pend

 \pstart {\RL{\RL{א\makebox(-1,8.75)[r]{\libertineGlyph{uni02DC}}גר.}
    הייסט       אַנדערער געגענריטטער.}} \pend

\pstart {\RL{א\makebox(-1,8.75)[r]{\libertineGlyph{uni02DC}}ז``
    "   "   אונד זאָ ווייטער.}} \pend
\pstart {\RL{\RL{ב\makebox(-1,8.75)[r]{\libertineGlyph{uni02DC}}ב}
    "   "   בעל. בתים}} \pend
\pstart {\RL{\RL{ב\makebox(-1,8.75)[r]{\libertineGlyph{uni02DC}}וו}
    "   "   בראַנטעוויין.}} \pend
\pstart {\RL{\RL{ב\makebox(-1,8.75)[r]{\libertineGlyph{uni02DC}}ע}.
    "   "   בעל קדושין}} \pend
\pstart {\RL{{ג\makebox(-1,8.75)[r]{\libertineGlyph{uni02DC}}ר}
    "   "   געגענריטטער.}} \pend
\pstart {\RL{{ה\makebox(-1,8.75)[r]{\libertineGlyph{uni02DC}}ג}
    "   "   האכצייטסגאַסט. (גאֶסטע)}} \pend
\pstart {\RL{{ה\makebox(-1,8.75)[r]{\libertineGlyph{uni02DC}}ר}
    "   "   האָר רעכט.}} \pend
\pstart {\RL{{ה\makebox(-1,8.75)[r]{\libertineGlyph{uni02DC}}ש}
    "   "   הערר שאָללעם (שולטהייס)}} \pend
\pstart {\RL{מוזיק. "   "   מוזיקאַנטען.}} \pend
\pstart {\RL{{ע\makebox(-1,8.75)[r]{\libertineGlyph{uni02DC}}גר}
    "   "   ערשטער געגענריטטער.
}} \pend
\pstart {\RL{{ע\makebox(-1,8.75)[r]{\libertineGlyph{uni02DC}}ה}
    "   "    עליו השלום.}} \pend
\pstart {\RL{{ע\makebox(-1,8.75)[r]{\libertineGlyph{uni02DC}}ם}
    "   "   ערשטעס מאֶדכען.}} \pend
\pstart {\RL{{ק\makebox(-1,8.75)[r]{\libertineGlyph{uni02DC}}ר}
    "   "   קרייצע.}} \pend
\pstart {\RL{{ש\makebox(-1,8.75)[r]{\libertineGlyph{uni02DC}}טהס}
  " " שולטהייס}} \pend



\pstart
 {{\begin{small}|\liningnums{142}|\end{small}}}

  \LR{8. September 1822}
\pend


       \endnumbering
  \end{Leftside}










\begin{Rightside}

  \beginnumbering

   \pstart  Erklärung der in diesem Lustspiel vorkommenden Wörter \pend


 \pstart {\RL{\RL{א\makebox(-1,8.75)[r]{\libertineGlyph{uni02DC}}גר.}
    }} \LR{\textit{heißt anderer Gegenritter}} \pend

\pstart {\RL{א\makebox(-1,8.75)[r]{\libertineGlyph{uni02DC}}ז``
    "   "   }} \LR{\textit{und so weiter}}  \pend
\pstart {\RL{\RL{ב\makebox(-1,8.75)[r]{\libertineGlyph{uni02DC}}ב}
    "   "   בעל. בתים}} \pend
\pstart {\RL{\RL{ב\makebox(-1,8.75)[r]{\libertineGlyph{uni02DC}}וו}
    "   "   }} \LR{\textit{Brandwein}} \pend
\pstart {\RL{\RL{ב\makebox(-1,8.75)[r]{\libertineGlyph{uni02DC}}ע}.
    "   "   }} \LR{\textit{Bal Kiduschin}} \pend
\pstart {\RL{{ג\makebox(-1,8.75)[r]{\libertineGlyph{uni02DC}}ר}
    "   "   }}\LR{\textit{Gegenritter}} \pend
\pstart {\RL{{ה\makebox(-1,8.75)[r]{\libertineGlyph{uni02DC}}ג}
    "   "   }} \LR{\textit{Hochzeitsgast (Gäste)}} \pend
\pstart {\RL{{ה\makebox(-1,8.75)[r]{\libertineGlyph{uni02DC}}ר}
    "   "   }} \RL{\textit{Horrecht}} \pend
\pstart {\RL{{ה\makebox(-1,8.75)[r]{\libertineGlyph{uni02DC}}ש}
    "   "}} \LR{\textit{Herr Schollem (Schultheis)}} \pend
\pstart {\RL{מוזיק. "   "   }} \LR{\textit{Musikanten}} \pend
\pstart {\RL{{ע\makebox(-1,8.75)[r]{\libertineGlyph{uni02DC}}גר}
    "   "   }} \LR{\textit{erster Gegenritter}} \pend
\pstart {\RL{{ע\makebox(-1,8.75)[r]{\libertineGlyph{uni02DC}}ה}
    "   "    }} \LR{\textit{olow hascholaum}} \pend
\pstart {\RL{{ע\makebox(-1,8.75)[r]{\libertineGlyph{uni02DC}}ם}
    "   "}} \LR{\textit{erstes Mädchen}} \pend
\pstart {\RL{{ק\makebox(-1,8.75)[r]{\libertineGlyph{uni02DC}}ר}
    "   "   }} \LR{\textit{Kreuzer}} \pend
\pstart {\RL{{ש\makebox(-1,8.75)[r]{\libertineGlyph{uni02DC}}טהס}
  " " }} \LR{\textit{Schultheis}}  \pend

\pstart

  \LR{8. September 1822}
\pend


\endnumbering

\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages


\end{document}
```